# question on quadratic expansion

Tags: quadratics

I have been trying to solve this question, but no luck so far, any help would be appreciated.

> Let $a,b,c > 0$ be such that $a^2 + b^2 -2bc =100, \ 2ab -c^2 = 100$. Then the value of $\dfrac{a+b}{c}$ is: ...
>
> (the options are $10$, $100$, $2$, $20$)

Comment: the options are 10, 100, 2, 20

Comment: $(a,b,c)=(10,40\pm 20\sqrt 3,20\pm 10\sqrt 3)$ satisfy the system, but $(a+b)/c\approx 2.3\quad\text{or}\quad 5.7$.

Comment: Please share the method that you used to arrive at the result.

Comment: I just set $a=10$. I think you might have a typo in the question.

Comment: I got the question from a question paper of a competitive exam. Thanks for the reply